# Using RAII for callback registration in c++

Tags: c++, c++11, callback, synchronization, raii

I'm using some API to get a notification. Something like:

```
NOTIF_HANDLE register_for_notif(CALLBACK func, void* context_for_callback);
void unregister_for_notif(NOTIF_HANDLE notif_to_delete);
```

I want to wrap it in some decent RAII class that will set an event upon receiving the notification. My problem is how to synchronize it. I wrote something like this:

```
class NotifClass
{
public:
    NotifClass(std::shared_ptr<MyEvent> event):
        _event(event),
        _notif_handle(register_for_notif(my_notif_callback, (void*)this))
        // initialize some other stuff
    {
        // Initialize some more stuff
    }

    ~NotifClass()
    {
        unregister_for_notif(_notif_handle);
    }

    void my_notif_callback(void* context)
    {
        ((NotifClass*)context)->_event->set_event();
    }

private:
    std::shared_ptr<MyEvent> _event;
    NOTIF_HANDLE _notif_handle;
};
```

But I'm worried about the callback being called during construction\destruction (Maybe in this specific example, shared_ptr will be fine with it, but maybe with other constructed classes it will not be the same).

I will say again - I don't want a very specific solution for this very specific class, but a more general solution for RAII when passing a callback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your concerns about synchronisation are a little misplaced.

To summarise your problem, you have some library with which you can register a callback function and (via the void* pointer, or similar) some resources upon which the function acts via a `register()` function. This same library also provides an `unregister()` function.

Within your code you neither can, nor should attempt to protect against the possibility that the library can call your callback function after, or while it is being unregistered via the `unregister()` function: **it is the library's responsibility** to ensure that the callback cannot be triggered while it is being or after it has been unregistered. The library should worry about synchonisation, mutexes and the rest of that gubbins, not you.

The two responsibilities of your code are to:

- ensure you construct the resources upon which the callback acts before registering it, and
- ensure that you unregister the callback before you destroy the resources upon which the callback acts.

This inverse order of construction vs destruction is exactly what C++ does with its member variables, and why compilers warn you when you initialise them in the 'wrong' order.

In terms of your example, you need to ensure that 1) `register_for_notif()` is called after the shared pointer is initialised and 2) `unregister_for_notif()` is called before the std::shared_ptr (or whatever) is destroyed.

The key to the latter is understanding the order of destruction in a destructor. For a recap, checkout the "Destruction sequence" section of the following [cppreference.com page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/destructor).

- First, the body of the destructor is executed;
- then the compiler calls the destructors for all non-static non-variant members of the class, in reverse order of declaration.

Your example code is, therefore "safe" (or as safe as it can be), because `unregister_for_notif()` is called in the destructor body, prior to the destruction of the member variable `std::shared_ptr<MyEvent> _event`.

An alternative (and in some sense more clearly RAII adherent) way to do this would be to separate the notification handle from the resources upon which the callback function operates by splitting it into its own class. E.g. something like:

```
class NotifHandle {
 public:
   NotifHandle(void (*callback_fn)(void *), void * context)
       : _handle(register_for_notif(callback_fn, context)) {}

   ~NotifHandle() { unregister_for_notif(_handle); }

 private:
   NOTIF_HANDLE _handle;
};

class NotifClass {
 public:
   NotifClass(std::shared_ptr<MyEvent> event)
       : _event(event),
         _handle(my_notif_callback, (void*)this) {}

   ~NotifClass() {}

   static void my_notif_callback(void* context) {
     ((NotifClass*)context)->_event->set_event();
   }

private:
    std::shared_ptr<MyEvent> _event;
    NotifHandle _handle;
};
```

The important thing is the member variable declaration order: `NotifHandle _handle` is declared after the resource `std::shared_ptr<MyEvent> _event`, so the notification is guaranteed to be unregistered before the resource is destroyed.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with thread-safe accesses to a static container that holds pointers to your live instances. The RAII class constructor adds `this` to the container and the destructor removes it. The callback function checks the context against the container and returns if it is not present. It will look something like this (not tested):

```
class NotifyClass {
public:
   NotifyClass(const std::shared_ptr<MyEvent>& event)
      : event_(event) {
      {
         // Add to thread-safe collection of instances.
         std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutex_);
         instances_.insert(this);
      }

      // Register the callback at the end of the constructor to
      // ensure initialization is complete.
      handle_ = register_for_notif(&callback, this);
   }

   ~NotifyClass() {
      unregister_for_notif(handle_);

      {
         // Remove from thread-safe collection of instances.
         std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutex_);
         instances_.erase(this);
      }

      // Guaranteed not to be called from this point so
      // further destruction is safe.
   }

   static void callback(void *context) {
      std::shared_ptr<MyEvent> event;
      {
         // Ignore if the instance does not exist.
         std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutex_);
         if (instances_.count(context) == 0)
            return;

         NotifyClass *instance = static_cast<NotifyClass*>(context);
         event = instance->event_;
      }

      event->set_event();
   }

   // Rule of Three. Implement if desired.
   NotifyClass(const NotifyClass&) = delete;
   NotifyClass& operator=(const NotifyClass&) = delete;
private:
   // Synchronized associative container of instances.
   static std::mutex mutex_;
   static std::unordered_set<void*> instances_;

   const std::shared_ptr<MyEvent> event_;
   NOTIF_HANDLE handle_;
};
```

Note that the callback increments the shared pointer and releases the lock on the container before using the shared pointer. This prevents a potential deadlock if triggering `MyEvent` could synchronously create or destroy a `NotifyClass` instance.

---

Technically, the above *could* fail because of address re-use. That is, if one `NotifyClass` instance is destroyed and a new instance is immediately created at the exact same memory address, then an API callback meant for the old instance conceivably could be delivered to the new instance. For certain usages, perhaps even most usages, this will not matter. If it does matter, then the static container keys must be made globally unique. This can be done by replacing the set with a map and passing the map key instead of a pointer to the API, e.g.:

```
class NotifyClass {
public:
   NotifyClass(const std::shared_ptr<MyEvent>& event)
      : event_(event) {
      {
         // Add to thread-safe collection of instances.
         std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutex_);
         key_ = nextKey++;
         instances_[key_] = this;
      }

      // Register the callback at the end of the constructor to
      // ensure initialization is complete.
      handle_ = register_for_notif(&callback, reinterpret_cast<void *>(key_));
   }

   ~NotifyClass() {
      unregister_for_notif(handle_);

      {
         // Remove from thread-safe collection of instances.
         std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutex_);
         instances_.erase(key_);
      }

      // Guaranteed not to be called from this point so
      // further destruction is safe.
   }

   static void callback(void *context) {
      // Ignore if the instance does not exist.
      std::shared_ptr<MyEvent> event;
      {
         std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mutex_);
         uintptr_t key = reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(context);
         auto i = instances_.find(key);
         if (i == instances_.end())
            return;

         NotifyClass *instance = i->second;
         event = instance->event_;
      }

      event->set_event();
   }

   // Rule of Three. Implement if desired.
   NotifyClass(const NotifyClass&) = delete;
   NotifyClass& operator=(const NotifyClass&) = delete;
private:
   // Synchronized associative container of instances.
   static std::mutex mutex_;
   static uintptr_t nextKey_;
   static std::unordered_map<unsigned long, NotifyClass*> instances_;

   const std::shared_ptr<MyEvent> event_;
   NOTIF_HANDLE handle_;
   uintptr_t key_;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two common general solutions for RAII callbacks.  One is a common interface to a `shared_ptr` of your object.  The other is `std::function`.

Using a common interface allows for one smart_ptr to control the lifetime of all the callbacks for an object.  This is similar to the observer pattern.

```
class Observer
{
public:
    virtual ~Observer() {}
    virtual void Callback1() = 0;
    virtual void Callback2() = 0;
};

class MyEvent 
{
public:
    void SignalCallback1() 
    {
        const auto lock = m_spListener.lock();
        if (lock) lock->Callback1();
    }

    void SignalCallback2() 
    {
        const auto lock = m_spListener.lock();
        if (lock) lock->Callback2();
    }

    void RegisterCallbacks(std::shared_ptr<Observer> spListener) 
    {
        m_spListener = spListener;
    }
private:
    std::weak_ptr<Observer> m_spListener;
};

class NotifClass : public Observer
{
public:
    void Callback1() { std::cout << "NotifClass 1" << std::endl; }
    void Callback2() { std::cout << "NotifClass 2" << std::endl; }
};
```

Example use.

```
MyEvent source;
{
    auto notif = std::make_shared<NotifClass>();
    source.RegisterCallbacks(notif);
    source.SignalCallback1(); // Prints NotifClass 1
}
source.SignalCallback2(); // Doesn't print NotifClass 2
```

If you use a C style member pointer, you have to worry about the address of the object and the member callback.  `std::function` can encapsulate these two things nicely with a lambda.  This allows you to manage the lifetime of each callback individually.

```
class MyEvent 
{
public:
    void SignalCallback() 
    {
        const auto lock = m_spListener.lock();
        if (lock) (*lock)();
    }

    void RegisterCallback(std::shared_ptr<std::function<void(void)>> spListener) 
    {
        m_spListener = spListener;
    }

private:
    std::weak_ptr<std::function<void(void)>> m_spListener;

};

class NotifClass
{
public:
    void Callback() { std::cout << "NotifClass 1" << std::endl; }
};
```

Example use.

```
MyEvent source;
// This doesn't need to be a smart pointer.
auto notif = std::make_shared<NotifClass>();
{
    auto callback = std::make_shared<std::function<void(void)>>(
        [notif]()
    {
        notif->Callback();
    });
    notif = nullptr; // note the callback already captured notif and will keep it alive
    source.RegisterCallback(callback);
    source.SignalCallback(); // Prints NotifClass 1
}
source.SignalCallback(); // Doesn't print NotifClass 1
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAICT, you are concerned that `my_notif_callback` can be called in parallel to the destructor and `context` can be a dangling pointer. That  is a legitimate concern and I don't think you can solve it with a simple locking mechanism.

Instead, you probably need to use a combination of shared and weak pointers to avoid such dangling pointers. To solve your issue, for example, you can store the event in `widget` which is a `shared_ptr` and then you can create a `weak_ptr` to the `widget` and pass it as a context to `register_for_notif`.

In other words, `NotifClass` has as `share_ptr` to the `Widget` and the context is a `weak_ptr` to the `Widget`. If you can't lock the `weak_ptr` the class is already destructed:

```cpp
class NotifClass
{
public:
    NotifClass(const std::shared_ptr<MyEvent>& event):
            _widget(std::make_shared<Widget>(event)),
            _notif_handle(register_for_notif(my_notif_callback, (void*)new std::weak_ptr<Widget>(_widget)))
            // initialize some other stuff
    {
            // Initialize some more stuff
    }

    ~NotifClass()
    {
            unregister_for_notif(_notif_handle);
    }

    static void my_notif_callback(void* context)
    {
            auto ptr = ((std::weak_ptr<Widget>*)context)->lock();
            // If destructed, do not set the event.
            if (!ptr) {
                return;
            }
            ptr->_event->set_event();
    }

private:
    struct Widget {
        Widget(const std::shared_ptr<MyEvent>& event)
                : _event(event) {}

        std::shared_ptr<MyEvent> _event;
    };

    std::shared_ptr<Widget> _widget;
    NOTIF_HANDLE _notif_handle;
};
```

Note that any functionality you want to add to your `NotifClass` should actually go into `Widget`. If you don't have such extra functionalities, you can skip the `Widget` indirection and use a `weak_ptr` to `event` as the context:

```cpp
class NotifClass
{
public:
    NotifClass(const std::shared_ptr<MyEvent>& event):
            _event(event),
            _notif_handle(register_for_notif(my_notif_callback, (void*)new std::weak_ptr<MyEvent>(event)))
            // initialize some other stuff
    {
            // Initialize some more stuff
    }

    ~NotifClass()
    {
            unregister_for_notif(_notif_handle);
    }

    static void my_notif_callback(void* context)
    {
            auto ptr = ((std::weak_ptr<MyEvent>*)context)->lock();
            // If destructed, do not set the event.
            if (!ptr) {
                return;
            }
            ptr->set_event();
    }

private:
    std::shared_ptr<MyEvent> _event;
    NOTIF_HANDLE _notif_handle;
};
```

Comment: Seems better, but you are leaking the weak_ptr. It will be better to use an atomic global

Comment: @user972014 Well, not really. All event loop systems I have seen receive a callback which is called when they want to destroy the context. That's where you should delete the weak ptr. But I didn't know the API of your event handler. 

And I'm not sure how you can solve that with a atomic global.

Answer (score 0):

Make certain, that the callback object is fully constructed, before registering it. Means, make the callback object a separate class and the registration/deregistration wrapper a separate class.
Then you can chain both classes into a member or base class relationship.

```
struct A
{       CCallBackObject m_sCallback;
        CRegistration m_sRegistration;
        A(void)
             :m_sCallback(),
             m_sRegistration(&m_sCallback)
       {
       }
};
```

As an additional benefit, you can reuse the register/unregister wrapper...

If the callback could happen in another thread, I would redesign this software in order to avoid this.
E.g. one could make the shutdown of the main thread (e.g. destruction of this object) wait until all worker threads are shutdown/finished.